# XMLSocket request not working from Postman

Tags: flash, postman, actionscript-2

I am able to make a request from actionScript using XMLSocket but not able to make a connection from postman.

Action Script Code:

```
var main_socket = new XMLSocket();
main_socket.onConnect = function(success)
{
   if(success)
   {
      main_socket.send("<data avatar_id=\"" + avatar_data.id + "\" password=\"" + user_pass + "\" />");
   }
   else
   {
      _root.FailReport("Top Socket connection is failed.\nCheck your Internet connection.");
   }
};
function ConnectToTopSocket()
{
   main_socket.connect(_root.server_ip,_root.top_socket_id);
}
```

Postman:
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFzOw.png)

I have tried making normal get/post request, adding ws:// and wss:// at the start of address but nothing seems to work

Comment: 1) I replaced the **AS3** tag to **AS2** tag because it is **AS2**, not **AS3**. 2) Have you set the *crossdomain* policy up on the server side? Security is the first probable reason to check: https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate-discussions/xmlsocket-not-connecting-in-browser-actionscript-2/td-p/6455326 Otherwise, you should probably keep in mind that **XMLSocket** is a weird class they had in **AS2** which is not a real **TCP** **Socket** implementation they introduced later in **AS3** and thus might have limitations (now forgotten as it is 15 years since obsolete).